# Extract string and some number of digits

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I want to extract a pattern that starts with `1.` in the string. After some research I found `stringr` package and `str_extract` function. But it is extracting the only first match so far.

```
 library(stringr)
 library(dplyr)

 clas <- c("1461CD_1.332C","1461CD_1.5C_242","1461CD_1.6CC_131")
      df <- data.frame(clas)

      df %>% mutate(clas = str_extract(clas, "1.{1,2}"))


clas
1  146
2  146
3  146
```

the expected output

```
clas
1  1.33
2  1.5
3  1.6
```

I would appreciate you also write down some explanations to your solution since regular expressions currently complicated topics for me:)

Comment: `str_extract(clas, "1\\.[:digit:]{1,2}")`.....? Periods are special characters so you need to escape them, then you need to specify that you only want the subsequent 1-2 digits.

Comment: Or you can just do this with `sub(".*(1\\.\\d{1,2}).*", "\\1", clas)`

Comment: @joran neat and clean. Thanks a lot! I understand my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the right regular expression, you currently want to match `1`, a literal `.`, and then two digits. In regular expressions, `.` indicates any character, so you need to escape it with `\`. However, because `\` is a special character in strings in R, that means you need to escape the `\` as well so you type `\\.`. Then, you want to match either one or two digits. It's correct to use quantifiers `{1,2}` to specify one or two, but you need to tell the expression that you want digits specifically. You can do this with `[:digit:]`, or the shorthand `\\d`. This gives the desired output:

```r
library(tidyverse)
clas <- c("1461CD_1.332C","1461CD_1.5C_242","1461CD_1.6CC_131")
df <- data.frame(clas)

df %>%
  mutate(clas = str_extract(clas, "1\\.\\d{1,2}"))
#>   clas
#> 1 1.33
#> 2  1.5
#> 3  1.6
```

Created on 2018-02-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

For more information on regular expressions and regex in R specifically, see the [chapter in R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html) and also look at the handy [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf) for `stringr` from RStudio.